# Как получить данные с гироскопа и акселерометра от Oculus Rift?

Tags: arduino, uart, rxtx

Имеется вот такой вот датчик от DK1(Дисплей сдох, шлем разлетелся на детали).
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Судя по тому что, DK1 - версия для разработчиков, а так же по тому, что на плате есть Test Points, я предполагаю что можно к нему как-то подключиться адруиной и получать данные от акселерометра и гироскопа.

Попробовал цепануться к 4 точкам, которые на картинке выше тестовых. Подключил 3v питания от ардуины, а TX с гироскопа подключил к RX3 Ардуины Мега.

Ну и перенаправил данные с Serial3 в Serial, что бы посмотреть что там летит. А летят нули. всегда. Везде.

Вопрос: Что я сделал не так?
Если знаете ссылки на хоть какой-нибудь datasheet к этой платке - буду признателен. Самому найти не удалось(

Comment: У платы есть [довольно обширная публично доступная документация](https://github.com/facebookarchive/RiftDK1/tree/master/Schematics).

Comment: @D-side, м-да, переоценил я свои возможности) Может подскажете, что куда цеплять?)
RX и TX подсоединил к ардуиновским TX/RX. На UARTEN подал 3.3v. Питание и землю подключил. 

Читаю байт и сразу отдаю его на вывод. У меня это выглядит просто как нули.

Comment: Не могу посоветовать по железу (только недавно полез в электронику), но судя по [коду](https://github.com/facebookarchive/RiftDK1/blob/master/Firmware/main.c#L133-L135) [прошивки](https://github.com/facebookarchive/RiftDK1/blob/master/Firmware/main.c#L172-L175) всё это может быть попросту выключено. И если я прав, то чтобы включить, потребуется перепрошивка.